# Android textView scroll

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview

I have been trying to develop an android app that contain an activity which is scrollable
and inside the activity, I have 2 textView which I want them to be scrollable as well.

My problem is that
whenever I touch inside the textView the scrolls show up but the main activity part which is the linearLayout directly steel the focus and no longer the textView scroll

the way I have it now is setup for the textView to scroll in the xml file I have done that.
and if I keep raising my finger and put it back on the screen trying to scroll the textView I can move a little bit but as I said, the layout that contains the textView capture the focus and leave me unable to scroll the textView.

I hope I did explain my problem very well.

Please any suggestion to help.

---

let me explain how the app is built first
first part is: the main(first) activity is a tabHost
which I defined as scrollable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" > 
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >   
<FrameLayout
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="422dp" >
</FrameLayout>
<TabWidget
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="63dp" >
</TabWidget>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</TabHost>
```

where I am having problem with is this activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@color/light_gray_color" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:weightSum="1" 
android:orientation="vertical"

android:baselineAligned="false">

<LinearLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_weight="0.04">

<TextView 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:textColor="@color/black_color" 
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
android:text="@string/display_label" 
android:id="@+id/display_label">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.83"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:orientation="horizontal" >


<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/english_scrollView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.03" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/display_english_textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="2px"
android:layout_marginRight="2px"
android:layout_weight="0.03"
android:background="@drawable/black_rectangle"
android:focusable="true"
android:paddingLeft="2px"
android:paddingRight="2px"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

</ScrollView>


<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/translation_scrollView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.03" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/display_translation_textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginLeft="2px"
android:layout_marginRight="2px"
android:layout_weight="0.03"
android:background="@drawable/black_rectangle"
android:focusable="true"
android:paddingLeft="2px"
android:paddingRight="2px"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:textColor="@color/black_color" />

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please add your code, then we can see whats going on, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should cut `<ScrollView>` out of the first xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >   
<FrameLayout
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="422dp" >
</FrameLayout>
<TabWidget
android:id="@android:id/tabs"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="63dp" >
</TabWidget>
</LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: Well, thanks for that but if I follow your suggestion then all the activities in the app will not be scrollable???

Comment: Umm, Did you try adding ScrollView inside Second xml instead of first XML yet?.. anyway, the result might same. It might about setting something like focusable  true false, which i don't know much. sorry, i'm not help much. wait for another answer :)

Comment: don't worry. I have tried to put ScrollView there while keeping ScrollView in the 1st XML but that was the problem.
I tried also to do something with the focus such as getFocus() but since I am very expert in it, I think that didn't do much.

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you have a vertically scrolling activity, which contains two vertically scrolling text views? If so, you can't do it. Its not just a poor design choice, its literally impossible to tell which view the user intends to scroll when they make swipe motion. You can have horizontal scrolling inside a vertically scrolling view, or vice versa. You can't have horizontal scrolling inside horizontal scrolling or vertical scrolling inside vertical scrolling.

I believe this is mentioned in the listview talk in the 2010 google io conference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70